# Reverse order of SQL query output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, reverse

I have a bit of a problem that I cannot solve. I am running the following through my database using PHP:

```
$strQuery = "select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10";
```

The results all come back fine and as expected. However, I then have to feed these into a line chart, but when I do so, they are obviously displayed in reverse as I have the DB to return them in DESC by Date which means the most recent will be the first returned.

Is there a way that after returning these results I can reverse their order before feeding the data to my chart?

Here is the full query (please don't comment about the use of *mysql* instead of *mysqli*; I didn't write that bit)

```
$strQuery = "select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10";

$result3 = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result3) {
    while($ors4 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
        $NumberResults2 = $ors4['Date'];

        $strQuery = "select AvGoalDifference as Average from LastResult where Date= '$NumberResults2'";

        $result4 = mysql_query($strQuery) or die(mysql_error());
        $ors3 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

        $strXML .= "<set label='" . $NumberResults2 . "' value='" . $ors3['Average'] . "' />";

        mysql_free_result($result4);
    }
}

mysql_close($link);

$strXML .= "</chart>";
$chart2 = renderChart("charts/Line.swf", "", $strXML, "AverageGD", 500, 260, false, true, true);

echo $chart2;
```

Comment: Probably so the OP only gets the 10 latest

Comment: because this will only return the first 10 results. I need it to return the last 10 but in the opposite order.

Comment: Duplicate of 10000000s exactly the same questions.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: Can you provide some candidates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can reorder that resultset by doing an outer select and ordering it the way you want (ASC):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
) as
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```

If this fails (as it would in PostgreSQL 9.3.4), use an alias for the inner *select* to make it as below:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
) as foo
ORDER BY foo.Date ASC;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I looked for ages for that answer, thanks. It did throw up the error 'Every derived table must have its own alias.' but I just had to add in the 'AS' to make it as follows:
     $strQuery = "select * FROM (select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10) AS Date ORDER BY Date";

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the query like this:

```
$strQuery = "select * FROM (select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY Date";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t forget to alias the inner selection or MySQL will produce an error.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
) aliasT
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this;

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select * from LastResult ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```